# Can Structuremap DefaultConventionScanner find non-public classes

Tags: structuremap

I have just started using StructureMap, having previously worked with Spring.Net. I love the DefaultConventionScanner and the ability to scan assemblies and use convention over configuration to find classes. But there seems to be a limitation that the classes that implement the interfaces must be public, whereas we like to keep out interfaces public and our implementations internal to an assembly.

Is there a way to ask the DefaultConventionScanner to find internal classes as well?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, and in fact the limitation that classes should be public applies to all of StructureMap - not just the convention scanners. You *can* register internal types manually with StructureMap if you make use of the InternalsVisibleTo attribute, but it is not well-supported or documented. You will not be able to make an ITypeScanner (like DefaultConventionScanner) that registers internal types because the AssemblyScanner only exposes exported types.

Comment: Noting that this answer is several years old...is this still the case?

Comment: Yes, it is still the case. "Behind the scenes, StructureMap is using the Assembly.GetExportedTypes() method from the .Net CLR to find types and ... " - http://structuremap.github.io/registration/auto-registration-and-conventions/

Comment: Just to drop an update here (having this question myself): in 4.7.1 it seems that Scan() is still limited to public types, but it is possible to manually register an internal class implementing a public interface, and even an internal class implementing an internal interface.